# How many frames deep is a modern graphics pipeline?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, metal, vulkan

Assume the pipeline is fully full: GPU waiting on vsync, GPU/driver command buffers all full, and thus user program blocked.

How many frames worth of data is in the (modern) pipeline?

For example: (4)

1. Frame in GPU front buffer
2. Frame in GPU back buffer
3. Frame in GPU command buffer
4. Frame in CPU driver command buffer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For traditional APIs (non-Command Buffer APIs), the only thing that really matters is how many buffers you are using. The graphics pipeline may be pipelined, but the pipeline is not so deep that multiple entirely separate frames can be in the middle of being processed at the same time. So the GPU's queue(s) and the GPU itself will generally only be processing a single frame.

And since there's no real way in those APIs to build command data for multiple entire frames, the number of frames you can have in flight will be limited by the number of actual buffers you use. The number of frames of latency would generally be the number of buffers + 1, representing the frame you're building.

For command buffer APIs, the number of frames generally is based on how much CPU memory you have. The number of buffers provides a minimum, but there is nothing technically stopping you from buffering dozens or hundreds of frames in advance. Outside of CPU memory.

Of course, that assumes that all of your per-frame data lives in CBs. If any of that data is in GPU-accessible memory (say, arrays of matrices and so forth), or you need to change descriptor sets between frames, then you now have another set of things to buffer. This imposes an additional limitation on how deep things can go.

Comment: Thank for the response. How do I know how many buffers I'm using? (this is the level of graphics knowledge I have :P) For example, in my projects, I only stup one framebuffer.

Comment: @user7226419: In OpenGL, you cannot directly control the number of buffers in the default framebuffer. So it doesn't really matter if you could get a count or not; you can't do anything with that information. For command-buffer APIs, you ask for a specific number of buffers.

Comment: Despite not being able to control the number of buffers, is there generally X buffers? Ex: for OpenGLES 2.0 implementations on iOS, Android.

Comment: In GLES 2.0, when using default display, the default is two buffers: front and back. After a rendering cycle, your app must call eglSwapBuffer(display, surface) to swap back and front buffer.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on which graphics card you're using, and which mode you've placed it in, but generally speaking, the answer is 1-3 frames (or 2-4, if you're counting the frame that is being pushed into the buffer as a frame).

- Without Vsync or any other kind of double-buffering strategy, there's nothing mandating that any more than 1 frame be kept in memory at any given time, being overwritten as soon as a new frame is being pushed into the buffer.
- When VSync is enabled, new frames are pushed into a second section of the frame buffer, and delay any future commands from executing until the "Vertical Sync" (hence the name, obviously) triggers, at which point the two frames are flipped.
- A third mode, uncommon to OpenGL but familiar to Vulkan and DirectX users, called "Letterbox mode", or sometimes called "Triple Buffering", keeps two "Back Buffers" for a total of three buffers:

  - One of the back buffers is reserved for use for when the Vertical Sync triggers.
  - The other back buffer receives completed frames directly, without delays
  - Whenever a Vertical Sync occurs, the roles of these two back buffers are switched.

Note that with Triple Buffering, the Host doesn't get blocked when the buffer is full.

The GPU may choose to buffer additional frames, like in your example, though this is more common to OpenGL/DirectX11- than it is to Vulkan/DirectX12+, since in those latter APIs, the Host is being much more explicit in terms of what the GPU is supposed to do, and I can't imagine a programmer that willfully expands the frame buffer. It's not really clear what benefit it would offer beyond what Triple Buffering already offers.

Comment: OK. So, empirically, using OpenGL with vsync on - I've noticed that: (1) As long as I'm able to get 2 CPU frames submitted within 32.2ms (doesn't matter if the first one took 27ms, and the second took 3ms) - then I observe no dropped frames. (2) However, failing to do so, results in a frame drop. What can I conclude about the platform's pipeline?

Comment: @user7226419 That's the natural behavior of VSync. If the second frame comes in even slightly past the cutoff for the Vertical Sync, the GPU will wait until the next one before presenting the frame.

Comment: The GPU didn't wait at all if the first frame missed the cutoff though. I'm assuming that is because there was a frame 0, already in the pipeline, ahead of the first one, that the GPU was able to display? I.e. at least 1 "latent" frame in the pipeline?

Comment: @user7226419 Possibly. Bear in mind of course that OpenGL is allowed to do lots of "weird" things because the graphics model it represents is so different from how modern GPUs work that tons of Driver Magic needs to happen to make everything conforming.